# What can symbolize "mold-breaker"?

Tags: icon, illustration, symbols

I've searched online for a very long while now but there seems to be no iconography or symbolism for mold-breaker. Internet only knows the Pokemon ability of the same name or mold, the disease.

It basically means breaking the mold, like we use ice trays to get identical ice cubes, right? Each pocket of the ice tray is a mold. We pour water in it and get ice in that particular shape.

The definition of mold or mould is:

> a hollow container used to give shape to molten or hot liquid material
>   when it cools and hardens.

Mold-breaker basically means:

> a person or thing that is boldly original or pioneering.

And here's my question: **If you wanted to show mold-breaker through an icon, how would you do it?**

Where will I use it: I need to identify our department in college as a mold-breaker, it's completely my idea and I didn't want to do something like "original" or "creative." Mold-breaker is selected to define our department in one word. The icon will be used on our classroom doors, in events where we participate, and some official documents as well. We will also paint or craft the icon in a big size. So far, here's what I've come up with:

[image: My take on an icon to represent "mold-breaker."]

I think the pouring part makes sense. I can use a fluid inside the text mold-breaker itself, the text working as the frame or container of the fluid. And then I break it in some places. But that's more like a logo idea. What I need is a standalone symbol or icon.

Comment: Where would you use this icon or symbol?

Comment: Sorry, I've added the context explaining my usage in the question body now.

Comment: Just realized what this reminded me of.. If you add a speech bubble arrow to one of the sides, it's basically the ["disable live chat on full screen mode icon"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Hd37.jpg) in Youtube.

Answer (score 2):

Here some ideas:

The first image I have in my mind while reading the question was the Babybel Cheese: the image of a breaking mold that reveals its interior

[image]

From there I started to look in Google for Mold Casting (*Image from [www.roboto.nyc](https://www.roboto.nyc/new-york-mold-making-service)*)

[image]

Here some ideas with a similar concept: the unmolding of a bust from its stone block

[image]

Going more *conceptual*, in an in-depth analysis of the concept, the both words combination imply a counterposition. The word *mold* is structure, block, wrapping and the word *break* attack all this.

[image: joker]

[image: joker II]

Answer (score 2):

Non-material subjects are tricky to associate with symbols and this one is no exception. I kind of agree with @ispaany you need to either show something suddenly accelerating, breaking out or something orderly, but placed out of order. Like a [spark](https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=spark&i=2403604), a [volcano](https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=volcano&i=1732598) or a [broken grid](https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=puzzle&i=2231545) but this also depends on your context and overall design.

Answer (score 1):

Mold break goes along with thinking outside the box to me. Something along this line immediately came to mind (quick stab at it). An explosion, or eruption outside the norm.

[image]